# Animated 3D model libraries

Tags: c++, animation, 3d, models

Hello fellow programmers. I've been to school and learned various things about graphics programming. But one thing we didn't learn, was which libraries were aviable. We mostly looked at OpenGL so that's what I've been doing the last weeks. Learning the modern version.

The thing is that I've come to think that OpenGL doesn't offer the easiest way of loading 3d animated models. And everything seem very, from the ground up... But I guess that is to expect, as OpenGL is a very low end library.

But I'm looking for a library that can load 3d models easily. As I've tried setting up my own, and it's not having the best of progress. And I'm willing to bet that someone else have already made an easy solution that beats my work by a long shot. I tried looking at the wiki page for 3d libraries. But there are so many to choose from... Any reccomandations?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favourite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You could try asking on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lib3ds](https://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/). 
Also [GLM](http://sevengeekwonders.guecks.com/?p=115) can be used to load models.
My recommendation would be to use some scenegraph like [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) if you are looking for some serious application development in OpenGl. OpenSceneGraph supports wide array of formats through plugins.